# My LINQ Query is Returning only 1 result

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-xml

My LINQ Query is only returning the first result (Class). Here is the code that I am using:

```
        XDocument xmlDoc = XDocument.Load("Decks/Test.xml");
        List<Cards> tempdeck = (from deck in xmlDoc.Elements("Deck")
                                select new Cards
                                 {
                                     Name = deck.Element("Type").Value

                                 }).ToList<Cards>();

        foreach (var item in tempdeck)
        {
            ((MessageBroker)App.Current.Resources["MessageBroker"]).GameLog.Add(item.Name.ToString());

        }
```

This is what my XML file looks like:

```
<Deck>
  <Type>
    <Name>Class</Name>
  </Type>
  <Type>
    <Name>stsfs</Name>
  </Type>
  <Type>
    <Name>Class</Name>
  </Type>
  <Type>
      <Name>Class</Name>
    </Type>
</Deck>
```

I am formatting it this way because when I get it to work I want to add multiple properties to the query - not just name.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It isn't clear from your sample, but it appears you have *one* `Deck` element with *multiple* `Type` child elements. Your code is assuming the opposite, i.e. multiple decks, each with one (or one interesting) type-child.

Try this instead:

```
( from type in xmlDoc.Element("Deck").Elements("Type")
  select new Cards { Name = type.Value }
).ToList()
```

A "cards" is produced from each type-child of the only deck.

If you *do* have multiple decks, go with Mark Cidade's answer.

Comment: Thanks Ani - that fixed my problem! I do not understand why I would use Mark Cidade's answer. Would either of you mind explaining it further to me? I suspect it will come in handy. Also one more question - I have a type that is expecting an INT instead of a string. I thought this:                                          Usage = (int)deck.Element("Usage").Value was the format it expected but I am getting the "cannot convert type string to int" error. What do I do to fix this?

Comment: @Stacey: Regarding the cast, try `(int)deck.Element("Usage")`. XElement has an explicit conversion operator to int (and other common types). Its `Value` property returns a System.String, which  doesn't. Regarding Mark's answer, it gets all of the type-child elements of all of the decks. If you had multiple decks and were trying to assemble a sequence of "cardses" from all of them, that would be the way to go. It translates into a `SelectMany` call.

Comment: Thank you - that fixed my casting issue. :) Also, the explination helps a lot. I apprecaite it!

Answer (score 1):

In your query, you only select from the single `Deck` element and then choose the first `Type` element. You need to select from each `Type` element:

```
    List<Cards> tempdeck = (from deck in xmlDoc.Elements("Deck")
                            from type in deck.Elements("Type")
                            select new Cards
                             {
                                 Name = type.Value

                             }).ToList<Cards>();
```